# using same zend_form_element multiple times

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

I'm building a Zend_Form.Having:

```
$file=new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setDescription('upload a picture:')
->setDestination(myPath);
$file->class="media[]";
$file->setDecorators(array(
'File',
array('Description',array('placement'=>'PREPEND','tag'=>'')),
array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'span','class'=>'myclass'))
));
```

I can't add the same element multiple times to the form with:

```
$form->addElements(array($file,$file));
```

**Do I need to create a custom form_element_file class so that I can register 
the exact same element with the form more than once?How?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have more than one identical `Zend_Form_Element_File` elements in your form you can just setup `setMultiFile` method, e.g.

```
$file=new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setMultiFile(2);
$form->addElement($file);
```

Hope this helps.